# I can't get my mobile version of site exactly centered

Tags: css

I'm having some odd space issues on the left of my site. For some reason there is slightly more space on the left than on the right in mobile view, thus looking off-centered. I'm guessing its off for desktop view as well, but its not noticeable. I can't figure out what is making it this way. http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/

```
/* ---------->>> MOBILE gap/space issues <<<-----------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

#pageWrapper { margin: 0;}

.sqs-layout .sqs-row .sqs-block:last-child {
     padding-bottom: 0;
     padding-top: 0;
  }}



/* ---------->>> MOBILE center logo <<<-----------*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {

        h1.logo {
            text-align:center;  
            margin-bottom: 20px !important;
            }}



/* ---------->>> MOBILE logo size <<<-----------*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {


.logo-image .logo img { 
    max-height: 110px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: auto;
  }

.social-links {
    padding-top: 20px; 
  }}
```

[image]

Comment: the code, the code, the code, the code, the code, the code

Comment: added above, sorry. using a template based site, and this is the code i have added.

Comment: the full code, the full code, the full code, the full code - including the markup/html - it will just make us work more easier towards your solution - no body in his right mind can trouble shoot that

Comment: i havent added any html except below, its all from squarespace.com.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
   document.getElementById('canvas').removeAttribute('id');
   document.getElementById('canvasWrapper').removeAttribute('id');
};
</script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the `margin: 5px;` on `.logo-image .logo img` in your mobile styles. The image with the margin may be wider than the div that contains the image and it comes off as being non-centered.

**UPDATE**

I took a look at your site, its actually the margin on the .slide selector. Add this in your mobile styles:

```
 .slide { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: are you able to tell me whats causing the large space above this slide? Im trying to match the bottom spacing.

Comment: no. he won't be able to tell you since you already accepted his answer.

Comment: #headerWrapper { margin-bottom: 0; } should fix that

Comment: the last spacing issue i have is on the about me page, there is no space under the image in mobile view, and there should be.

Comment: `.sqs-layout .sqs-row .sqs-block:last-child { padding-bottom: 34px; }`  Here you go

Comment: you rock, i appreciate it a lot

Comment: now it made more space below the image which is why i was told to make it      .sqs-layout .sqs-row .sqs-block:last-child { padding-bottom: 0px; }